# How to make a secure-boot compliant boot CD

Tags: boot, uefi

I've found quite a bit of information floating around on the Internet about how to *install* Linux onto a *harddisk* and get Secure Boot to work with it. But I can't find a single shred of information about how to make a *bootable live CD*. Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

I'm using Kiwi to build a CD based on OpenSUSE 13.1. The actual OpenSUSE installation DVD boots in Secure Boot mode, but I'm unsure how to replicate this feat myself. Does anybody know what magic button I need to press?

I can't test this, but I imagine the boot CD already works with EFI. But it doesn't work with Secure Boot. (And why would it? It isn't signed with anything.)

(Just to clarify: The test machine I have available does not allow you to disable Secure Boot. You can disable EFI completely and revert to legacy BIOS, but you can't turn off just the Secure Boot part. Which isn't terribly helpful, but anyway...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved!

- Get Kiwi to build a CD that works in BIOS mode. (Mine is hybrid; not 100% sure whether that's required or not.)
- Find the line that says

`<type image="iso" hybrid="true" boottimeout="1" boot="isoboot/suse-13.1" flags="clic"/>`

and change it to

`<type image="iso" hybrid="true" firmware="uefi" boottimeout="1" boot="isoboot/suse-13.1" flags="clic"/>`

- Build your CD. Kiwi automatically takes care of everything to make it work in (U)EFI mode, even with Secure Boot switched on.

Important: Only the *64-bit* version of Kiwi handles this. The 32-bit version only did half the job, leaving me with a CD that boots into Grub and then gets "stuck". It seems that Grub2-EFI refuses to boot a 32-bit OS...

If only I had known about this secret undocumented switch, I could have saved myself an entire month of heartache!

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is incomplete.**

So here is a summary of what I know so far...

The BIOS, of course, looks at the boot block to figure out if a device is bootable, and if so, boot it. EFI doesn't care about such things; it looks for an EFI System Partition (ESP). If it finds one, it boots the configured program. In the case of a *removable* device, there won't be anything configured, so it seems to default to booting whatever file is named `/boot/bootx68.efi`.

I can confirm that simply putting such a file onto a CD-ROM *does not work*. In fact, the OpenSUSE boot DVD works on EFI systems with Secure Boot, but simply copying all its files onto another DVD doesn't work. So it appears you have to do something other than simply having the boot loader exist on the disk somewhere.

Looking at the OpenSUSE DVD, it appears that the ISO-9660 "system area" contains a valid MBR, which defines two partitions, one of which is an ESP. Whether this is integral to why EFI-boot works or whether this is merely to allow writing the ISO image to a USB stick, I don't know. I'm still researching the matter...

**Update:**

Looking at [the Kiwi file for the OpenSUSE DVD](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/openSUSE:Factory/_product:openSUSE-dvd5-dvd-x86_64/openSUSE-dvd5-dvd-x86_64.kiwi?expand=1), it appears that Kiwi has a completely undocumented option `firmware="uefi"`. Setting this option causes `isohybrid` to be called with the `--efi` switch. If I also add a couple of files grabbed from the official OpenSUSE DVD, I can get as far as a Grub menu. The OS doesn't *boot*, but that's presumably down to Grub...